# JavaScript unable to reference this object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reference this.foo in an object I created, however this is referencing the HTML element that triggered the function. Is there any way that I can preserve the references to this in an object when it is called via an event?

Here is an example of what is going on:

```
$('document').on('click','button',object.action);

var object = {
  foo : null,
  action : function(){
    this.foo = "something";
  }
};
```

The error I would receive is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no variable 'var'
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just an example demonstrating my issue.

Comment: Put quotes around it "var" might work.

Comment: you can't use reserved keywords in javascript like var

Comment: `var` is a reserved word. You can't use that as a property name.

Comment: @Eric.K.Yung It won't.

Comment: @Juhana actually after quoting it will work as it is used just as an ordinary string :) `var a = {"var": 1}; a['var']`

Comment: object.action should be object.action.bind(object)

Comment: I changed var to foo so that I can get real answers in lieu of "var is a reserved keyword" responses sorry for the miscommunication.

Comment: @AdamZieliński It won't fix the *actual problem*. You dont' get "has no variable var" error for using `var` as a key.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/rsPMB/1/) so long as I change `$('document')` to `$('body')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve `this`, you should probably attach your event like that:

`$('document').on('click','button',function() { object.action() });`

Also, if you use this object as it is presented in the question, you may as well use `object` instead of `this`:

```
var object = {
  foo : null,
  action : function(){
    object.foo = "something";
  }
};
```

Also you might want to familiarize yourself with the [Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [Call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), and [Apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) - jQuery uses these behind the scenes to replace your `this` with HTML Element;

Also, `var` is a reserved keyword and you should not use it for a property name; if you really want to do that, use a string `"var"` and access it via `[]` notation like this:

```
var a = {"var": 1}
a['var']
```

Comment: This won't work in IE below 9. See the Browser Compatibility table at the bottom.

Comment: that's true in regard to `.bind()`, it is in there just as a reference as the actual solution does not involve using it

Comment: By wrapping the function calls in a function I am able to call this.foo in my objects.

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.var` to `object.var`

The problem that `this` refers to context of where it was called from.
You call `object.action` from click event on button, so `this` is `#<HTMLInputElement>` here.

And, as it was already said, don't use reserved words like `var` as variable names

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `object` as the `this` value using [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
$('document').on('click','button',function(){object.action.apply(object); });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Your `this` should be referencing `object` but it is not most likely because of the use of `var` which is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in JavaScript.

Comment: just a note, apply is redundant in this context - `object.action()` is enough as `action` is defined directly in the object literal

Comment: right, it is redundant I just put it there as an example of how to fix any issues with `this` not referencing the correct object.

Answer (score 0):

**var** ist **reserved** word in JavaScript.

This works fine:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

var myObj = {
  myVal: null,
  action:function(){
    this.myVal = "something"; 
  }

};
myObj.action();
console.log(myObj.myVal);
```

});

Here [link to JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ugebAHI/5/edit)

I hope i could help.